# Calloc() is asigning previously assigned memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free, calloc

I'm developing a C project , and it turns out that in a specific moment, i call calloc() function and it assigns a memory block which is already in use . How is that possible ? I've checked my memory-allocation usages and for every time i call  malloc/calloc then i call free(pointer_to_the_allocated_memory) . So, it's not a memory leak issue neither a twice-freed pointer.
I don't paste my code since it is for a colleage work and i haven't sent it yet.
Any type of help/advice is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using something like valgrind to track/debug your memory usage.

Comment: Note that each program has its own virtual memory space.

Comment: Could you post something similar to the original? There are a lot of people who ask about proprietary code that they don't want to share directly, but they usually give an example. Can you recreate the situation on a smaller scale?

Comment: Also, when you say "already in use", do you mean by the same process, or is it by another process? Because like @sjsam said, the operating system gives each process their own memory space, which may appear to overlap.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that two pointers point to the same place.

```
p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
/* ... */
p2 = p1;
/* ... */
free(p1);
/* ... */
p3 = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* may allocate the block already used by p2 */
```

Note that it is often not that obvious. It may happen via pointer arithmetics (i.e. `p2++`), or different parts of this may be done in different functions.

Another possibility is that you free a pointer without noticing it:

```
p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
foo(p1); /* this function calls free(p1) */
p2 = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* may allocate the block already used by p1 */
```

Comment: Should probably note that while possible, it is not likely and there is no way to know that the scenario you wrote would happen. It's all very compiler implementation specific.

Comment: Given the fact that calloc() "assigns a memory block which is already in use", it is likely.  To assign a memory block which is in use, the block should be either freed or never allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer user31264